# Select distinct from Muiltiple columns into one column

Tags: sql, select

I have this:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC
Dog        Soda       Book
CatIce     Juice      Notebook      
Bird       Water      Pencil
Dog        Water      Notebook
```

By using this select:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC from table
```

I wanna a list like this:

```
ColumnD
Bird
Book
Cat
Dog
Ice
Juice
Notebook      
Pencil
Soda
Water
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UNION

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM table

UNION

SELECT ColumnB
FROM table

UNION

SELECT columnC
FROM table
```